# What should I press on the Double Slides?

Tags: project-diva-future-tone

This is the first time that I have played on Extreme, so I just learned about the the Double Slides that point either to the Left or Right.

Here is an example on Tell Your World, where there is a set of Double Slides pointing to the right.

[image]

What should I press when the Double Slides appear? I have tried all of the following and none of them worked:

- L1 or R1 alone
- L1 + Left Analog to the Left, or R2 + Right Analog to the Right
- L1 + L2 or R1 + R2

I checked the [digital manual](https://miku.sega.com/futuretone/manual/index.html) and there is nothing related to the Double Slides.

Just in case, here is the button configuration that I'm using currently:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just learned that you can't mix L1/L2/R1/R2 with the analog sticks, so your only options are:

#### L1/L2 and R1/R2

For this one, you need to change L1 and L2 to Slider Left and R1 and R2 to Slider Right. Then, when sliders come up, you press L1 + L2 when pointing to the Left or R1 + R2 when pointing to the Right.

#### Analog Sticks

This one is easier and you don't loose the macros on L1/L2/R1/R2. You just need to move both the Left And Right analogs to the direction shown on the screen. For example, Double Left Slides will require you to move both analog sticks to the Left.